# updated sharethis plugin is not working on ajax

Tags: sharethis

Recently sharethis plugin is updated. i have successfully installed and it was working fine. but i am unable to load the buttons on ajax calls. 
I have added this script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=propertystring&product=inline-share-buttons"></script>
```

Old code using the following

```
stButtons.locateElements();
```

is not working any more.

Please note i am using custom share button.

Comment: Hello Bilal, Have you got an answer?

Comment: Any one got solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

I actually found the solution for this, at least it worked for me. Run this after the template has loaded:

```
__sharethis__.initialize()
```